# while loop in ezpdf

Tags: php

I am having  trouble with ezpdf. it works fine for first row of recordset, however I am unable to get all rows of the recordset in ezpdf. it seems that ezpdf somehow ends working after the first record and just creates the pdf file anyway.

Here is what I am doing.

Getting order details from a transaction table and generating tickets based on the quantity in the order. So let's say it has 3 tickets to generate in an order, the pdf will only generate the ticket for first row. It does not accumulate the data of 2nd and 3rd row.

Here is my code.
http://pastebin.com/DMaZUpqw

Please help.

Thanks
Ali

Comment: Welcome to SO! For starters: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi]

Comment: Second: Please post your **relevant** code here please.

Comment: Have you checked whether your query does actually return multiple lines or just one?

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa yes, I know about the old queries, but this a big site and cannot change things now :(

Comment: @StefanDochow yes, it returns all rows, I tested that already.

Comment: @HuzaifaAli Everyone has legacy projects. np (well it sucks but hey) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well if I got that correctly it is supposed to print multiple of those tickets onto on pdf document. Why is this line commented out?:

```
#$pdfid = $pdf->newPage(1, $pdfid, 'after');
```

wouldn't you have to add another page before going on printing stuff there?

If $RowsTkt actually returns multiple rows, there is no way, it only iterates once.
Have you checked (by dumping an index or such) that the loop actually does not execute three times as you implied?

Regards
STEFAN